# UIButton frame is changing according to device language

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have a UIButton set up in the top left corner of my view controller in storyboard. When i run the app on a device localized in english (left to right language) the button's position is where it i positioned it, however when i run the app in a right to left language, the button moves to the opposite side of the view controller - see screenshots below. Has this something to do with constraints/other settings?

[image: The way I want it - LTR]

[image: The way it is displayed when the device language is one that is RTL]

Comment: Did you use a left constraint or a leading constraint? I think the latter is language dependent, and the former is not.

Comment: yes @rdelmar after reading more here in the apple constaint docs, I think that is the issue. However, whenever i try to set the constraint for the left space of the button, it adds a leading constraint - how can i explicitly set the constraint as a left constraint? (Whenever i do Add New Constraint it adds it as leading as i mentioend!)

Comment: @rdelmar I should mention that I have added all constraints in storyboard, and would like to add that left constraint as well through the storyboard if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a horizontal constraint in IB, it adds it as a leading or trailing constraint. To change that to left or right, edit the constraint (double click on a constraint in the list). In the pull down menu for an item, uncheck the line that says "Respect Language Direction".